# How to send email to multiple recipients

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I want to send emails to multiple recipients in ASP.NET MVC and I find it challenging. My code only sends to the first email address on the list, but I want to send to about 400 recipients at once. These recipients' addresses are stored in an SQL Server database. Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendBulkEmail(EmailAddress ea, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderEmail"].ToString();
    string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderPassword"].ToString();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


        SqlDataReader reader;
        using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email_address FROM Newsletter", cs);

            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            myFunctions m = new myFunctions();
            var emailList = m.LoadEmails();
            var emails = new List<AllEmailAddresses>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emails.Add(new AllEmailAddresses
                {
                    EmailAddress = Convert.ToString(reader["email_address"])
                });
            }

            foreach (AllEmailAddresses email in emailList)
            {
                try
                {
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.chijiokechinedu.com", 25);
                    client.Timeout = 100000;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

                    //MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, email.EmailAddress, ea.EmailSubjest, ea.EmailBody);
                    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.EmailAddress));
                    mailMessage.Subject = ea.EmailSubjest;
                    mailMessage.Body = ea.EmailBody;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                    if (postedFile != null)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(postedFile.InputStream, fileName));
                    }

                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                    return RedirectToAction("EmailSentSuccessfully", "Home");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "email failed to send!");
    }
    return View(ea);
}
```

Comment: It should be very straightforward. You're looping at the wrong spot. You need to loop this: `mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.EmailAddress));`, not loop the actual sending of the email. You want to add multiple recipients, not send multiple emails. And remove that try/catch. There's no point catching an exception if you're just going to rethrow it. And `AllEmailAddresses` is a terrible name for an object that only contains one email address.

Comment: In order to avoid timeouts and other issues I'd strongly recommend you to extract all the data you need from the database, close the database connection and then send the emails

Comment: Thanks guys. its working now, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the redirect (`return RedirectToAction("EmailSentSuccessfully", "Home");`) to the bottom of that function as at the moment as soon as you send the first email it will redirect

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendBulkEmail(EmailAddress ea, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderEmail"].ToString();
    string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderPassword"].ToString();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


        SqlDataReader reader;
        using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email_address FROM Newsletter", cs);

            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            myFunctions m = new myFunctions();
            var emailList = m.LoadEmails();
            var emails = new List<AllEmailAddresses>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emails.Add(new AllEmailAddresses
                {
                    EmailAddress = Convert.ToString(reader["email_address"])
                });
            }

            foreach (AllEmailAddresses email in emailList)
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.chijiokechinedu.com", 25);
                client.Timeout = 100000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

                //MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, email.EmailAddress, ea.EmailSubjest, ea.EmailBody);
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.EmailAddress));
                mailMessage.Subject = ea.EmailSubjest;
                mailMessage.Body = ea.EmailBody;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                if (postedFile != null)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(postedFile.InputStream, fileName));
                }

                client.Send(mailMessage);
            }

            // ** redirect after sending all the emails
            return RedirectToAction("EmailSentSuccessfully", "Home");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "email failed to send!");
    }
    return View(ea);
}
```

However you might want to remodel your approach and put this on back of a queue  due to the following questions:

1) What happends if after 10 emails one fails? what do you do with the rest?

2) This is a fairly long running process, what happends if the connection between the client and the server get segregated?

Comment: Thank you Kevin Smith, I moved (return RedirectToAction("EmailSentSuccessfully", "Home");) to the bottom and its now working perfectly. I really appreciate your help. Secondly, can you assist me with how I will remodel my approach?

Comment: Totally depends on what you're running it on really... I'd go with the idea of queuing them up to be processed later down the line, either something like AWS SQS or Azure Storage Queues etc...

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like you are going to sent the exact same email to everyone?
If that’s the case maybe you should consider using BCC for all your recipients!
That way you only have to send one email. Most Mailservers need some kind of throttling when you bulk sent mail, so the less items the better.

Comment: Thank you Joost Verdaasdonk so much. I wonder if this code will achieve that. MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
                    foreach (AllEmailAddresses email in emailList)
                    {
                        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(email.EmailAddress));
                    }